# Can't access WP site with Wamp 2.5 from intranet

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp, windows-server-2008-r2, wampserver

I've installed Wampserver 2.5 and Wordpress on a windows server 2008 R2 at my work place and manged to get a website working.
Everything is fine on that machine.

The problem is when trying to access the site from a different machine on the intranet.

I get a 403 forbidden error, given by the Apache server.

I guess that means I need to set the right permissions on the Apache server.

I wonder if the fact that wamp 2.5 uses virtual hosts now has any affect.

Currently these are the settings I've got on the httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from 127.0.0.1
#    Allow from ::1
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And these are the settings on the phpmyadmin.conf:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
   Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
#     Deny from all
#     Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
Allow from all
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Your help is appreciated.

EDIT:

After reintalling wampserver 2.5 I followed their guide [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482) for adding virtual hosts, and after each step I made sure that I can reach Wamp's main screen from another machine.
I lost contact after doing this step:

```
Find this line in httpd.conf
 #Virtual hosts
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
And just remove the `#` to uncomment the Include line.
```

But if I don't do this step than I can't login to the Wordpress site from the machine it's installed on (same one as wamp).

So I still need your help.

EDIT 2:

Here's my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal"
     ServerName hista-portal
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What IP/URL are you using to access it from the other machine(s)?

Comment: http://h-portal/hista-portal
h-portal being the name of the server and hista-portal being the site's url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to Apache 2.4 commands rather than mixing Apache2.2 and 2.4 commands.

Virtual Hosts are a Help and not a hinderance.

Look at what you are doing

```
APACHE24 is defined in httpd.conf if you are using WAMPServer2.5
```

you are using Apache 2.4

This will probably fix your issue.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And the phpmyadmin config file

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
     Require all granted
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
  </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

But you would be better to use syntax like

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

instead of `Require all granted`, so access is allowed from just your internal network subnet, assuming your subnet ip addresses start with 192.168.1

And if all else fails check out the manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html

**EDIT SECOND PROBLEM**

If you did the uncomment properly, you have now included the `wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` into `httpd.conf` so I would guess there is a problem in the edits you made in that file.

To get Apache to help with the diagnosis of the problem :-

First open a command windows

```
cd \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
httpd -t
```

This should parse the config files and report any errors with a filename and line number where the error occured.

Fix the error and rerun above command until you get a message `Syntax OK`

Comment: RiggsFolly, thanks for the elaborate answer.
It didn't do the trick but after reinstalling wampserver 2.5 I found where the problem is.
But I still don't know how to solve it.
I'd appreciate it if you could read my edit to the original question and see if you could help again.
Thanks

Comment: I assume you uncommented just the line `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and not the LABEL line above it?

Comment: Yes, just this line. Now, I made another small progress: in httpd-vhosts.conf I changed the lines that say `Require local` into `Require all granted`. And now I can reach the wampserver main page from another machine, but still, when I click the link to the site I get the 403 error.
The IT guy in my company says it doesn't seem right that it says `ServerName localhost` in that file, but we don't know what to do instead.

Comment: Show your httpd-vhosts.conf file in your question

Comment: Just saw the edit to your answer.
Went through it and I got syntax ok on the first try.

Comment: Actually, now I noticed it's not a 403 error, but a "server not found error". Again, I only get that when clicking the site's link. The main wampserver site loads fine.

Comment: RiggsFolly, I hope you're still with me cause you're my last hope.
I've noticed another thing that might give a clue to where the problem is, but it's too long to describe in a comment and since I made some progress since the original question I'll just open a new one (I hope it's ok).

Comment: Problem finally solved. Can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731467/wordpress-portal-not-accessible-from-intranet/24732672#24732672