# Wordpress portal not accessible from intranet

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtualhost, windows-server-2008-r2, wampserver

I'm trying to build a portal for my organization, using Wordpress.
I have installed windows server 2008 R2, Wampserver 2.5 and the WP 3.9.1.
I followed the Wampserver's guide to setting a virtual host for the site.

On the server machine everything works ok. Localhost at the address bar shows Wamp's main page and the link to the site shows only the site's name (without localhost) and when I click it it loads ok.

The problem is when trying to access it form a client machine on the intranet.
When writing the server machine's name in the address bar I get the Wamp's main page without a problem.

The link to the site shows only the site's name and when I click it I get an error message saying the browser could not find a server at that address.

When I manually write in the address bar the server machine's name / the site's name I do get to the site but it's broken - onlythe text shows.

What is wrong with my settings?

This is the relevant part of httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And this is the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal"
    ServerName hista-portal
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal">
       AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

- This is a continuation of another question I asked, but since the situation has changed, with the help of RiggsFolly, and there were many edits it was too complicated to continue there and I thought it would be best to start a new one. I hope I'm not breaking the site's rules.

Comment: I would check the firewall...

Comment: Thanks, but there's no firewall on the server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Now there is a number of ways of getting you running and a right way.

**Quick and very dirty way:**

Apache treats the first VHOST in the vhost file as the default, which is why currently you are getting to the WAMPServer homepage and not your WP site. So you could just reverse the order of the VHOST definitions, like this :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal"
    ServerName hista-portal
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal">
       AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when you use the routers WAMP ip address you will get to the WP site.

**Much better way**

Get a free account with DYNDNS or NOIP, there are others.

This will let you create a pseudo domainname something like `hista-portal@dyndns.net`

Then you create a new Virtual Host definition with that as the Server name like so :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal"
    ServerName hista-portal
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal">
       AllowOverride All
        Require local
        # maybe also allow access from your local lan
        Require ip 192.168.1  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal"
    ServerName hista-portal.dyndns.net
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hista-portal">
       AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note I have made the localhost `Require local` so any accidental access will get an error returned, this helps stop drive by sniffing on your site by people who just use an ip address.

Remember you are using `Name Based Virtual Hosting` so Apache really wants to see a name sent by the browser that matches one of the `ServerNames` it has in its Virtual Host definitions.

Comment: OK, first method works perfectly but have to add that the site address has to be changed in WP settings as well, which means the site name has to be removed and only the server machine name should be left (http://h-portal in this case).

Why is the second method better?

Comment: Simply because your users can use a rememberable name and not an ip address. Also method one realise on Apache falling back to a default rather than going to a specific site address, so it would only work for one site, not if you have 2 sites you wanted to serve. You are right, the site would have to be fixed to use the new domain name to work properly but that is documented on the WP site. Basically if you want to server a WordPress site it is best to start with a VirtualHosts rather than add it later.

Comment: Actually I am using a site name and not an ip address.
But I've changed my site into a multisite and now I can't get into the subsites because of the names mess.
So you're saying the second method should solve this?

Comment: Now the IT person in my org says I can't use method 2 since it's an external service and the portal resides in a secured intranet.
So I have to make it work with method 1 somehow.

Comment: Well get the IT guy to add your site name to the company DNS

Comment: He's already done that. When I turn the WP site into a network I get a warning message that the wildcard DNS settings have a problem.
Maybe that's the reason for not being able to access the subsites...

Comment: In the Wordpress site they say:
In the httpd.conf file, or in the include file containing the VirtualHost section for your web account, add a line like this:

ServerAlias *.example.com .  

Also create a wildcard DNS record like:

*.example.com A 192.0.43.10 .

I guess in my case these lines should be added to the vhosts file.
But should I add the alias to the default vhost, the portal's one or should I create a new one alltogether?
And where should the line with the IP be added in the file?

Comment: This question is actually solved so I started a new one for the subsites problem, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775443/cant-get-to-subsites-wildcard-subdomains-probably-misconfigured-in-apache.
Thank you RiggsFolly for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Well, kinda.

In the Wordpress site settings, I added to the site URL the server machine's name at the begining.
Now, on a client machine, when I write at the address bar the sever machine's name / site name, I get to the site and it works perfectly.
Before, I just got text cause all the links to the images were wrong.

The link in the main Wamp site is still wrong but I don't really need it.
I'm gonna give the portal users the direct link to the site anyway.