# Can't get to subsites. Wildcard-subdomains probably misconfigured in Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, wildcard, wampserver, wildcard-subdomain

I'm building a portal for the organization I'm working at.

The portal is a Wordpress site using Wampserver 2.5, intalled on a Win server 2008 R2.

It's working fine and accesible from other machines over the intranet, thanks to the helpful and patient RiggsFolly.

But now, I have changed it into a network of sites so that I can build sub-portals for the different departments in my organization.

During that change Wordpress gave this warning message: `Warning! Wildcard DNS may not be configured correctly!`

Wordpress has a page explaining how to configure wildcard subdomains on Apache - http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains.

I tried following it but the explanation lacks details and I'm probably doing something wrong.

On the machine where the servers and site are installed, when I write `http://hipo` (hipo is the current site name) in the browser's address bar, I get to the site fine.

But when I write `http://depa.hipo` (depa is a subsite I created successfully), the address changes into `http://www.depa.hipo/` and the browser says it didn't find a server at that address.

I have probably set the ServerAlias line wrong in httpd-vhosts.conf, and also I didn't add the line `*.example.com A 192.0.43.10`, or in my case `*.hipo A <rightIP>`, cause I wasn't sure where to add it in the file.

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file. Your help is appreciated!

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hipo"
     ServerName hipo
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hipo">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hipo"
     ServerName subsites.hipo
     ServerAlias *.hipo
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hipo">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The bit you didnt know how to do is for your tech support to add to the company DNS. Go chat with your tecky and get them to update the DNS Server with that wildcard DNS A Record

Comment: OK, he added the record, but the address still adds `www.` at the begining and says it can't find a server there.
Is everything ok with my httpd-vhosts.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition does not have a ServerAlias so try adding one like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hipo"
     ServerName hipo
     ServerAlias www.hipo
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hipo">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Everything is working now!
RiggsFolly, thanks again for all your help and patience.
You sure saved me.